# Hiding a view servlet in a Java MVC web application?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications, servlets

I'm using a very simple MVC framework, [Bear Bibeault's Front Man](http://www.bibeault.org/frontman/), which, for those not familiar, is pretty similar to Spring MVC (in concept at least).

For most cases, I am using a JSP as my view. To prevent direct access to the view, I place the JSP files inside the WEB-INF directory.

However, in some cases I need to use a servlet to represent my view. For instance I have a view servlet that generates PDF, which you shouldn't do in JSP. The problem I'm having is these views are directly accessible by typing the name of the view in the URL. Granted the view throws an exception because it doesn't have a proper model in the request (since it is not hitting the model building page controller), but I would like the view servlet to be hidden from the user, much like my JSP views are.

**How do I prevent direct accessing of the view servlet?**

---

### Related Question:

> [Protecting internal view layer template pages in servlet applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156002/protecting-internal-view-layer-template-pages-in-servlet-applications)

Comment: This may be a dupe, didn't see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156002 until after I created this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step is to use a proper security model to prevent access to your files.
Rather than using the side-effect of the WEB-INF directory being inaccessible as a URL (Which, BTW, is not guaranteed to work for all web servers) you should use the  &  elements in your web.xml file to define which directories can or can't be accessed via a direct URL.

Once you've done this, you should be able to map your PDF view to a URL, protect that URL, via your web.xml file, then forward to the view form your MVC controller/action (Much like you forward to your JSPs)

See [the Sun site](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3669/bncbk?a=view) for more info on the security constraint.

Comment: Why do so many MVC frameworks use the WEB-INF directory to hide views there is a better way to do it?

Comment: It's not the framework, per se, just habits that people get into (Including the developers of the frameworks, who unintentionally give the impression that this is the way to do it).

The correct way to do it, according to Sun, anyway is via the security contraints - spend a short while reading the article I linked to, Google a bit, and you should have it sorted fairly quickly.

Comment: Correction, works great under Tomcat, but our production server is Jrun, which is J2EE 1.3, and it doesn't like the web.xml with a security-constraint attribute. Oh well, good suggestion for people not on obsolete crappy servers.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, nemo. Which version of JRun are you using? What are the symptoms of JRun 'not liking' web.xml? Have a look at this article - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/server_archive/articles/jrun_authentication.html - which suggests that JRun 3.0 support security constraints.